# UDP server only responding to one client

Tags: c, sockets, udp, client, server

I have some C code for a UDP server and client (It must be UDP, not TCP). I am facing trouble while trying to send a message to all the connected clients.

When the server receives a message from a client, it can answer back to the very same client, but it's not serving the other connected clients.
Can someone please help me with this ?

server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "lib/colors/colors.h"
#include "lib/simlist/simclist.h"



typedef char* string; // to make life easier

#define PORT "9034"

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa){
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

    int main(void){

        fd_set master;    
        fd_set read_fds;  
        int fdmax;        
        int listener;     
        int newfd;     

        struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; 
        socklen_t addrlen;

        char buf[1024];    
        int nbytes;

        char remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

        int yes = 1;       
        int i, j, rv;

        struct addrinfo hints, *ai, *p;

        FD_ZERO(&master);    
        FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &ai);

    /* simlist initialisation */
        list_t clients;
        typedef struct client{
            fd_set socket_number;
            char *username[100];
        } client;

        list_init(&clients);

        client new_client;
        string client_username;
    /* end of simlist */

        if ( rv != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
            exit(1);
        }

        for(p = ai; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {

            listener = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);

            if (listener < 0) {
                continue;
            }

            setsockopt(listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));

            if (bind(listener, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
                close(listener);
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (p == NULL) {
            printf( "failed to bind\n");
            exit(2);
        }

        freeaddrinfo(ai);

        if (listen(listener, 10) == -1) {
            perror("listen");
            exit(3);
        }

        FD_SET(listener, &master);
        fdmax = listener;

        for(;;) {
            read_fds = master;
            if (select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
                perror("select");
                exit(4);
            }

            for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {

                if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) {

                    if (i == listener) {
                        addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
                        newfd = accept(listener,
                            (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr,
                            &addrlen);

                        if (newfd == -1) {
                            perror("accept");
                        } else {
                            FD_SET(newfd, &master);
                            if (newfd > fdmax) {
                                fdmax = newfd;
                            }
                            // @TODO
                            // insert into list user, ip, port combination
                            printf("new connection from %s on socket %d\n",
                                inet_ntop(remoteaddr.ss_family,
                                    get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr),
                                    remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN),
                                newfd);
                        }
                    } else {
                        nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
                        printf("nb of bytes received : %d \n", nbytes);
                        if ( nbytes <= 0) {
                            if (nbytes == 0) {
                                printf("%s socket %d hung up \n", warning_msg(""), i);
                                // delete user from list
                            } else {
                                perror("recv");
                            }
                            close(i);
                            FD_CLR(i, &master);
                        } else {
                            // data received from client
                            for(j = 0; j <= fdmax; j++) {
                                // send to everyone!
                                if (FD_ISSET(j, &master)) {
                                    // except the listener and ourselves
                                    if ( j != listener || j != i) {
                                        printf("available sockets %d \n", j);
                                        printf("SENDING : %s\n", buf);
                                        send(j,buf,nbytes, 0);
                                        // if (send(j, buf, nbytes, 0) == -1) {
                                        //  perror("send");
                                        // }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "lib/colors/colors.h"

#define PORT "9034"

#define MAXDATASIZE 1024

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa){
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd, numbytes;  
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: ./client [hostname] [username] \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
        continue;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("client: connect");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

if (p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
    return 2;
}

inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);
printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

char *username = argv[2];
send(sockfd, username, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0);

while(1){
    char word[MAXDATASIZE];
    printf(">");
    fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
    send(sockfd, word, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0);
    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("RECEIVED : %s\n",buf);    
    }

}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);


buf[numbytes] = '\0';

printf("client: received '%s'\n",buf);

close(sockfd);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you want it (send message to each *connected* client) needs to address each client individually. You can do that with looping over your connection table sending each client a message. That's not much different from what you have already.

If you want to do "real" broadcasting and if it doesn't matter if other *not connected* machines receive the message as well, look up broadcasting (only works within the same network segment if you do not have special IP helpers configured on your routers) and/or multicasting.

Comment: I just want to know why it's not working, the way I am doing it, only the sender client is receiving his own message

Comment: probably because you didn't code it? To send a message to a number of clients, you need to keep a list of them in the server. I can see you have a list defined, but you never assign to it.

Comment: isn't this the thing of a fd_set ?

Comment: umm, no. UDP connections work with a request-response pattern. What you are trying to do is to send a response without a request. There is nobody listening on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

> I have some C code for a UDP server and client.

No you don't. This is a **TCP** server. You are specifying `SOCK_STREAM`; you are calling `listen(),` `accept()`, and `connect():` it's TCP.

> (It must be UDP, not TCP)

Then you need to start again.

> I am facing trouble while trying to send a message to all the connected clients.

There are no connections in UDP.

Comment: what's the best efficient way to store clients each time they connect and send messages to all of them based on that list ?

Comment: @f0unix They don't connect in UDP at all, so there  is no list. Your question doesn't make sense in the UDP context, and your code isn't UDP code. You aren't making any sense at all.